# TransferState doesn't work with ProductSearchService

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

We faced the issue with ProductSearchService. It requests search data many times - in SSR mode and in CSR mode. This behavior causes the PLP page to flicker. This's also reproduced OOTB.
I thought if I configured routing load strategy and it will solve the issue but it didn't help. Maybe does anybody know how to fix this behaviour?

updated: We use SPARTACUS 4.2.1

Comment: Please provide a used version of Spartacus

Comment: @MichałGruca "@spartacus/storefront": "4.2.1"

Comment: @MichałGruca have you any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is related to this issue, which is aimed for 5.0 release.
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/14770

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Thank you. We will follow the ticket @BrianGJ